# error: explicit instantiation of class OESystem::OEUnaryPredicate<OEChem::OEMolBase> in namespace 'OEChem' which doesn't enclose namespace 'OESystem'

Tags: c++, qt, namespaces, c++17

```
namespace OEChem
{

// Molbase, atombase and bondbase predicates
// Predicate implementations and predicate declarations (global)

#ifdef _WIN32
template class OECHEM_API OESystem::OEUnaryPredicate<OEMolBase>;
template class OECHEM_API OESystem::OEUnaryPredicate<OEMCMolBase>;
#endif
// Generic

template<class Arg>
class OEHasIdx : public OESystem::OEUnaryPredicate<Arg>
{
  unsigned int _idx;
 public:
  OEHasIdx(unsigned int idx) : _idx(idx) {}
  bool operator () (const Arg &arg) const
  { return _idx == arg.GetIdx(); }
  OETYPENAME OESystem::OEUnaryFunction<Arg,bool> *CreateCopy() const
  { return new OEHasIdx<Arg>(*this); }
};

typedef OEHasIdx<OEAtomBase> OEHasAtomIdx;
typedef OEHasIdx<OEBondBase> OEHasBondIdx;
typedef OEHasIdx<OEConfBase> OEHasConfIdx;

template<class Arg>
class OEIdxSelected : public OESystem::OEUnaryPredicate<Arg>
{
public:
  OEIdxSelected(const OESystem::OEBitVector &bv) : _bv(bv), _ap(0) {}
  OEIdxSelected(const std::vector<bool> &vb)     : _bv(),   _ap(0)
             { OESystem::OECopyBits(_bv, vb); }
  OEIdxSelected(const bool *ap, unsigned int sz) : _bv(sz), _ap(0)
  {
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < sz; i++)
    {
      if (ap[i]) { _bv.SetBitOn( i); }
      else       { _bv.SetBitOff(i); }
    }
  }
  OEIdxSelected(const bool *ap) : _bv(), _ap(ap) {} // user owns array
  bool operator()(const Arg &a) const
  {
    return (_ap == (const bool *)0) ? _bv[a.GetIdx()] : _ap[a.GetIdx()];
  }
  OETYPENAME OESystem::OEUnaryFunction<Arg,bool> *CreateCopy() const
  {
    return new OEIdxSelected<Arg>(*this);
  }
private:
  OESystem::OEBitVector _bv;
  const bool *_ap;
};
```

Getting error in template class OECHEM_API OESystem::OEUnaryPredicate;
template class OECHEM_API OESystem::OEUnaryPredicate; these two lines in above code.

error: error: explicit instantiation of class OESystem::OEUnaryPredicateOEChem::OEMolBase in namespace 'OEChem' which doesn't enclose namespace 'OESystem'

I have downloaded Openeye api for c++ and tried to import oechem.h and getting these errors in QT creator.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: You are only allowed to explicitly instantiate in a scope where a definition of the instantiated entity would be allowed, i.e. only in scopes directly enclosing the scope to which the entity belongs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be outside of your OEChem namespace

```
template class OECHEM_API OESystem::OEUnaryPredicate<OEMolBase>;
template class OECHEM_API OESystem::OEUnaryPredicate<OEMCMolBase>;
```